# Complex pentagon-shaped buttonset in HTML CSS and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a complex pentagon-shaped buttonset. How can i achieve the example below in HTML CSS and/or javascript?

Sorry, i did not try anything yet, i would like to hear some best approaches.. My first thought would be slicing everything and use background-images, but i'm afraid of some overlap issues..

[image]

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Maybe use an SVG?

Comment: hmm.......yes! what did you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529781/how-to-draw-a-simple-pentagon-in-canvas

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about SVG in HTML5.

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_inhtml.asp
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.htm

You can almost draw anything using SVG, however, creating a design as complex as you just showed us will require a lot of work and patience. Anyway, SVG is your best bet in this case.